# How to get wallet balance of a token given token contract address and wallet address in Solidity?

Tags: solidity

```
(bool success, bytes memory data) = address(tokenContractAddress).call(abi.encodeWithSignature("balanceOf(address)", wallet address));
```

This is my current idea where I call the balanceOf function from the token Contract, however it does not seem to be working. May I know if there is any issues with my code or this should be done in another way?

Answer (score 1):

Just import the [`IERC20`](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/7c5f6bc2c8743d83443fa46395d75f2f3f99054a/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol) interface from OpenZeppelin and then do this:

```
IERC20(contractAddress).balanceOf
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned Paul, you can use interface, of course if the contract of the Token is based on ERC20 (or other liker Erc1155). This is the best practice